# Mysql TRIGGER sync 2 databases same server

Tags: mysql, triggers

mysql 5.6.37
phpmyadmin   4.4.15.7
same server

the TRIGGER is created in database_2
it should sync database_2 from updates in database_1

```
DELIMITER |
USE database_2;
CREATE TRIGGER trgSync 
AFTER UPDATE ON database_1.table_1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE database_2.table_1 a INNER JOIN database_1.table_1 b USING(tb_id)
SET 
a.published = b.published;
END;
```

I get

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax ... near 'CREATE TRIGGER trgSync AFTER UPDATE ON ...' at line 2

thanks for helping

Comment: I doubt that you can store triggers in databases other than those where the table lives.

Comment: on the same server yes  it is possible, but I cannot find the way to do it

Comment: Hm I get trigger in wrong schema error when I try to replicate this

Comment: then change USE database_2; with your db

Comment: Have you tried on line 2 USE database_2| instead of the semicolon since the previous line sets the DELIMITER to the | character.

Comment: yes but I get a schema error

Comment: I already told you that. Change your use statement to match the schema in in the create statement.

Comment: in the question asked here I have no error in the schema, if you know how to sync 2  table between 2 databases on the same server could please write the code
if not please let someone else answer

Answer (score 0):

Apart from a question mark about how you are using delimiters the trigger is fine if you try to park the trigger in the correct schema. Hopefully this code is convincing enough for you

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> use sandbox;
Database changed
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop trigger if exists trgsync;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'users' and table_schema in('sandbox','test');
+--------------+------------+
| table_schema | table_name |
+--------------+------------+
| sandbox      | users      |
| test         | users      |
+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select trigger_schema,trigger_name from information_schema.triggers where trigger_name = 'trgsync';
Empty set (0.04 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> DELIMITER |
MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TRIGGER trgSync
    -> AFTER UPDATE ON sandbox.users
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> UPDATE test.users a INNER JOIN sandbox.users b USING(id)
    -> SET
    -> a.name = b.name;
    -> END |
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> delimiter ;
MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> select trigger_schema,trigger_name from information_schema.triggers where trigger_name = 'trgsync';
+----------------+--------------+
| trigger_schema | trigger_name |
+----------------+--------------+
| sandbox        | trgSync      |
+----------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,name from sandbox.users union all select id,name from test.users;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | aaa  |
|  2 | bbbb |
|  3 | zzz  |
|  1 | aaa  |
|  2 | bbbb |
|  3 | zzz  |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> update sandbox.users set name = 'aaaa' where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> select id,name from sandbox.users union all select id,name from test.users;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | aaaa |
|  2 | bbbb |
|  3 | zzz  |
|  1 | aaaa |
|  2 | bbbb |
|  3 | zzz  |
+----+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you attempt to park it in the wrong schema

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> use sandbox;
Database changed
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop trigger if exists trgsync;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select table_schema,table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'users' and table_schema in('sandbox','test');
+--------------+------------+
| table_schema | table_name |
+--------------+------------+
| sandbox      | users      |
| test         | users      |
+--------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select trigger_schema,trigger_name from information_schema.triggers where trigger_name = 'trgsync';
Empty set (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> DELIMITER |
MariaDB [sandbox]> use test;
ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test;'
MariaDB [sandbox]> CREATE TRIGGER trgSync
    -> AFTER UPDATE ON sandbox.users
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    -> UPDATE test.users a INNER JOIN sandbox.users b USING(id)
    -> SET
    -> a.name = b.name;
    -> END |
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Command line returns an unknown database error and my gui(heidisql) returns a trigger in wrong schema error.

Comment: thank you for your time ! I ll try to do something with it